# Copying file from one folder to another in laravel causes error File not found

Tags: laravel-5.6

i want to copy a file from Modification folder to proposal folder with the file file name store in variable $modfilename but i am getting error file not found at public/files/Modification/abc.pdf

i did not make any changes in filesystem.php , 
Here is my code,

```
$modfilename=$finalize->modified_proposal;
$modfilename=$modfilename.''.".pdf";

Storage::copy('public/files/Modification/'.$modfilename, 'public/files/Proposal/'.$modfilename);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your folder has 777 permission and want to create a folder dynamically, you can try creating a folder first and then run the command. It will not give the error.